# An elementary proof about filters

Tags: set-theory, filters

I [my book draft](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) I have proved a theorem which is equivalent to the following. My proof uses ultrafilters, Galois connections, and the cofinite filter.

Let $S$ be a set of filters on some set $U$.

Theorem. $\bigcap\bigcap S = \bigcup\{\bigcap F \mid F\in S\}$.

Note that in my book it is formulated instead like this: $\operatorname{Cor}\bigsqcup^\mathfrak{F} S = \bigsqcup^\mathfrak{F}\{ \operatorname{Cor} F \mid F\in S \}$.

I am interested in an elementary proof of this theorem, not using advanced apparatus as in my book.

Also: Can it be generalized to filters on posets more general than the powerset on $U$?

Comment: I don't think you wrote what you meant. Suppose $U=\{1,2,3\}$, let $G$ be the filter generated by $\{1,2\}$, let $G'$ be the filter generated by $\{2,3\}$, and let $S=\{G,G'\}$. Then $\bigcap S$ is the filter consisting of only $U$, so $\bigcap\bigcap S=U$. But $\bigcap G=\{1,2\}$ and $\bigcap G'=\{2,3\}$, so $\bigcap\{\bigcap F:F\in S\}=\{1,2\}\cap\{2,3\}=\{2\}$. On the basis of this example, I conjecture that the first $\bigcap$ on the right side of the equation was intended to be $\bigcup$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: You are right, the first $\bigcap$ on the right side of the equation was intended to be $\bigcup$. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an elementary proof. The $\supseteq$ direction is rather formal. Consider any one of the sets being intersected on the left side, i.e., any set $X$ that is in all the filters in $S$, and consider any of the sets being unioned (that's not a word, but you know what I mean) on the right, i.e., $\bigcap F$ for some $F\in S$. Then, since $X\in F$, we have $\bigcap F\subseteq X$.  Taking the union over all $F\in S$ (while keeping $X$ fixed), we get that the right side of your equation is $\subseteq X$.  Since that's true for all $X\in\bigcap S$, we infer that the right side is a subset of the left side.  (This argument seems to work in much greater generality; you just need that the relevant infima (in place of intersections) exist in your poset.)

For the $\subseteq$ direction, consider any element $x\in\bigcap\bigcap S$, and suppose, toward a contradiction, that it is not an element of the union on the right side of your equation.  So, for each $F\in S$, we have $x\notin\bigcap F$, and therefore we can find a set $A_F\in F$ with $x\notin A_F$.  Let $B=\bigcup_{F\in S}A_F$ and notice that $B\in F$ for every $F\in S$ (because $B\supseteq A_F$).  So $B\in\bigcap S$.  But, by choice of the $A_F$'s, we have $x\notin B$, contrary to the assumption that $x\in\bigcap\bigcap S$.